# How can i change ItemContainer in itemscontrol

Tags: wpf, canvas, itemscontrol

I have been using Canvas for ItemsPanel.

```
<Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Canvas/>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

And override two method  by inheriting the ItemsControl.

```
protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
{
    // ABCItem is example. like ListboxItem.
    return (item is ABCItem);
}


 protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
 {
     return new ABCItem();
 }
```

But when i used ItemsPanel by Canvas,
It throw exception.

> Cannot explicitly modify Children collection of Panel used as ItemsPanel for ItemsControl. ItemsControl generates child elements for Panel.

How can i use ItemsPanel by canvas with custom Itemcontainer?

thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ItemsControl uses the top-level Panel in the ItemsPanelTemplate. So you shouldn't put the Canvas in a Grid:

```
<Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
     <Setter.Value>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```